# How do I determine which PIP library to download manually? (Parsing pypi.org json output)

Tags: python, pip

I have all the details of my machine (Linux, Python 3.8). How can I determine which wheel file PIP **would have downloaded without using `pip install` or `pip download`?** The goal is to get the package details from (example) https://pypi.org/pypi/pyarrow/json and then get the size of the wheel.

The json output is given, but there can be **multiple versions** for a single release. Are there standardized values that I can match? Or how pip determines which version? Or some way to know what my machine would have downloaded?

Seems like `python_version` can have a variety of values like py2.py3, py3, py2, cp36...

Comment: you can use `digests`

Comment: you're only interested in what version will be installed based on your python version, or also based on other dependencies (like requirements.txt) ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 digests don't allow to correlate which version PIP installs unless you already know the sha256 or md5 (which means you would have to download it or install beforehand)

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski based on Python version, OS system. And to keep it simple, only the base library itself excluding requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Import statements:

```py
import requests
import re
```

Function to compare versions using pattern from `setup.py` (to best of my knowledge):

```py
def compare_versions(compare_statement: str) -> bool:
    try:
        decompose = re.search(r"(\d+(\.[\d*]+)*)([^\d*.]+)(\d+(\.[\d*]+)*)", compare_statement)
        gr = decompose.groups(0)
        print("GR", gr)
        ver_l, op, ver_r = gr[0], gr[2], gr[3]
        print("components", ver_l, op, ver_r)
        ver_l, ver_r = ver_l.rstrip(".*"), ver_r.rstrip(".*")
        if op == ">":
            return ver_l > ver_r
        if op == "<":
            return ver_l < ver_r
        if op == ">=":
            return ver_l >= ver_r
        if op == "<=":
            return ver_l <= ver_r
        if op == "!=":
            return ver_l != ver_r
        if op in ("~=", "=="):
            # ~= is a bit more complex, but "approximately" :)
            return ver_l == ver_r
        return False
    except Exception as err:
        print("ERROR!", compare_statement, err)
        return False
```

Initialize basic variables:

```py
url = r"https://pypi.org/pypi/{package}/json"
packages = ["pandas", "pyarrow", "numpy", "awswrangler", "apache-airflow"]
versions = dict()
```

Parse json to get most standardized pattern for python compatibility comparison (from `requires_python`):

```py
for package in packages:
    versions[package] = dict(
        map(
            lambda x: (
                x[0], 
                max(x[1], key=lambda a: a["upload_time"])["requires_python"] if x[1] else []
            ),
            requests.get(url.format(package=package)).json()["releases"].items()
        )
    )
```

Actual check (might be integrated in the above loop) - my goal was to keep code clear, not concise:

```py
my_python_version = "3.7"
versions_suitable = dict()
for package in packages:
    versions_suitable[package] = []
    for v in versions[package]:
        conditions = versions[package][v]
        if not conditions: continue 
        for c in conditions.split(","):
            if compare_versions(my_python_version + c):
                print(f"For {package} version {v}, with conditions {conditions} is suitable!")
                versions_suitable[package].append(v)
    if versions_suitable[package]: print(f"Best version suitable: {max(versions_suitable[package])}")
```

`print`-s could be removed, there's a lot of parsing and broad assumptions, hence I kept code verbose.